# LotusScript NotesHTTPRequest RunOnServer Proxy Issue

Tags: proxy, httprequest, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

1.Is it possible to set up a proxy for NotesHTTPRequest? I have searched and found that it is currently not supported.

2.Due to different network conditions for different users, I would like to be able to use a proxy to make external httpRequest calls. Therefore, I have decided to use RunOnServer to execute NotesHTTPRequest.

The proxy settings are configured in the server document, but I am still unable to make external calls. How can I configure RunOnServer to use the proxy and make API calls to external networks?

Answer (score 0):

Per HCL documentation
https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0073832

setting proxy for NotesHTTPRequest should be possible inserting proxy settings for libcurl in server/client Environment variable (don’t forget to restart after settings made).

Anyway, NotesHTTPRequest is too limited in functionality, so if your are trying to write an application, not a one-time task, I would recommend using any java based http client in procedure via ls2j.